# Find ways an Integer can be expressed as sum of n-th power of unique natural numbers.code giving wrong output

Tags: c++, recursion

I have t test cases.
Given two numbers x and n, find number of ways x can be expressed as sum of n-th power of unique natural numbers.

The approach is to either select a number or move to the next one.The ans returned is stored in an array since I am using the dp approach.

This is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int arr[101];

int func(int x,int n,int ind)
{
    if(arr[x]!=-1)
    {
        return arr[x];
    }
    if(x==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(ind>=(sqrt(x)+1))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(x<0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //you can either take ind or just move to the next one

    arr[x]=func(x-pow(ind,n),n,ind+1)+func(x,n,ind+1);
    return arr[x];
}

int main()
{

    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t)
    {

        int ans=0;
        memset(arr,-1,sizeof(arr));

        int x,n;
        cin>>x>>n;

        int ind=1;
        ans=func(x,n,ind);

        cout<<"printing the ans\n"<<ans;
        t--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

for input
1
10 2
I am getting
printing the ans
-297160607
though the ans is 1

Comment: Not noticing any questions in this.

Comment: First of all please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Why not step through your code for this example and check the state as you go, so you can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: _"though the ans is 1"_ How do you know?

Comment: Think about the order of your conditionals for a few minutes. ([Trace-printing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01733eea6abcb863) the values provides very clear clues.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inserted a simple debug output in `func`. For the given input "1 10 2" `x` sometimes gets negative. This causes UB when accessing the array, but does not necessarily crash.

You already check if x is less than 0, but *after* using x. Move the `if(x < 0)` up and you are done.

In general to avoid such mistakes you should use stl containers like `std::array` or `std::vector`. Though it is not garantued by the c++ standard, many implementations will performe bounds checking on `operator[]` when compiled in debug mode. Or you can use `at()` where the standard garantuess bounds checking.

Comment: There's also `.at(index)` to _force_ bounds checking, which throws an exception if out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks, this might be worth mentioning.